# How would I set a timer where my node could jump every two seconds in Swift Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, touch

I have this code where my node could jump every time I tap the screen. I want there to be like a two or three second wait before I could make the node jump again when I tap the screen. How would I do this? Thanks!

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch

    theHero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 250))
    theHero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "jumpman")
    println("works")


 }
```

Comment: Do you want to just ignore all taps until two seconds have passed? Or do you want to remember that there was a tap during the two second refractory period, and jump again as soon as the period is over if there was a tap?

Comment: The second one is what Im looking for.

Comment: Is this `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method in your `SKScene`?

Comment: Yes it is in the SKScene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using SpriteKit, the easiest way to handle this is by using the `SKScene.update` method. SpriteKit calls this method once per frame, if the scene is presented and not paused.

In `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, just set a flag indicating that a jump was requested. In `update:`, check whether the flag is set and sufficient time has elapsed since the last jump. If both are true, clear the flag, update the "last jump time" property, and jump.

```
class MyScene: SKScene {

    let theHero: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    var lastJumpTime: NSTimeInterval = 0
    var jumpIsPending: Bool = false
    static let JumpCooldownSeconds: NSTimeInterval = 2

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        jumpIsPending = true
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        jumpIfNeeded(currentTime)
        // ... other per-frame stuff
    }

    private func jumpIfNeeded(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        if jumpIsPending && lastJumpTime + MyScene.JumpCooldownSeconds <= currentTime {
            jumpIsPending = false
            lastJumpTime = currentTime

            theHero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 250))
            theHero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "jumpman")
            println("works")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks man it works perfectly. I tried doing it with a runBlock but it wasn't working for me. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a question. I never used static before...what does it do?

Comment: As I used it here, `static` has two effects: it associates the property with the class (`MyScene`) itself rather than instances of the class, and it acts as though declared `final`, meaning subclasses cannot override it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what properties are for - to *maintain state* between invocations of methods. Each time you do jump, store the current time (the touch's `timestamp`) in a property. Now, the next time, look at the current time (the *new* touch's `timestamp`) and subtract the stored time. If it isn't more than 2 seconds, do nothing. If it is, store the new current time and jump.